# How to convert 24:00 hours to 12:00 format

Tags: pseudocode

I need help with my pseudocode assignment: convert 2400 hours to 12 format

**Design an algorithm that will prompt for and receive the item expresses in 2400 format (e.g. 2305 Hours), convert it to 12 hour format (e.g. 11.05pm) and display sentinel time of 9999 is entered.**

```
Prompt for hrs, mins
Get hrs, mins                               
DOWHILE(hrs NOT = 99) AND (mins NOT = 99) // If hrs & mins not = to 99 then it will run if not it will stop
    IF (hrs = 00) THEN  // midnight. 0030. It will + 12 and display 12:30am
        format = am
        time = hrs + 12
        Display hrs, ":" , mins, format
        ELSE
        IF (hrs > 12) THEN  // afternoon. 1630. It will – 12 and display 4:30pm
            format = pm
            hrs = hrs – 12
            Display hrs, ":" , mins, format
        ELSE
            IF (hrs < 12) THEN      // from midnight 0100 to 1159. It will display AM
                format = am
                Display hrs, ":" , mins, format
                IF (hrs = 12) THEN      // if format is 1230. It will display 1230PM
                    format = pm
                    Display hrs, ":" , mins, format
                ENDIF
            ENDIF
        ENDIF
    ENDIF

    IF (hrs < 0) OR (hrs > 23) THEN // hrs less than 0 or more than 23 is error. 
        Display ‘Invalid hour input’
        IF (mins < 0) OR (mins >59) THEN    // mins less than 0 or more than 59 is error. 
            Display ‘Invalid mins input’
        ENDIF
    ENDIF

    Prompt for hrs, mins    // you prompt again , we are still in the loop until we hit 9999
    Get hrs, mins
ENDDO           // which stop here because it’s 9999
```

Am i doing correctly? Please advice. New student here! many thanks!

Comment: Some indenting would be helpful. What part are you unsure of?

Comment: Would be nice to see that someone edited while you are doing it too :D Apart from that, this code fails on sentinel code, as if I pass 12:99 it stops when it should only on 99:99

Comment: So the error is DOWHILE (hr<>99) OR (min<>99)? What should i use instead? DOWHILE (hr<>99) AND (min<>99)?

Comment: Yes, already better. Update post, indent code with 4 spaces, and indent the inside of IF/WHILE etc with one more tab

Comment: Sorry i dont get what you mean.

Comment: just posted an error ? IF (hrs < 0) OR (hrs > 23) i should use AND instead am i right?

Answer (score 1):

Well, depending upon how your professor expects your pseudocode to look like, what you have should work fine, I think. A few of the lines are a bit redundant, though. You could combine the out-of-bounds checking of the hours and minutes into one `IF` statement. You could then set your `time` variable to `"am"` by default, which would turn your `IF - ELSE IF - ELSE` to a single `IF - ELSE`. Oh, and not that I'm sure it matters much, but rather than using `hours = hours + 12` when `hours = 0`, you could probably just do `hours = 12.` Again, what you have should work just fine, I think.

EDIT: Ah... again, not sure if this matters, but have a way to possibly terminate the program might be useful, too. Otherwise, you'll be stuck in your loop forever, it seems.

EDIT 2: Here's what I would do...

```
done = false

DOWHILE !done
    PROMPT hours, minutes
    GET hours, minutes

    IF hours < 0 OR hours > 23 OR minutes < 0 OR minutes > 60
        DISPLAY "Invalid Time"
    ELSE
        format = "AM"

        IF hours > 12
            format = "PM"
            hours = hours - 12
        ELSE IF hours == 0
            hours = 12
        ELSE IF hours == 12
            format = "PM"

        DISPLAY hours ":" minutes format
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
    PROMPT "Are you done?"
    GET done
ENDLOOP
```

Comment: As it stands now, the code will never execute when it is noon (12:00pm), for your `IF` statement to handle it is within the `IF(hours < 12)` block; there's no way the hours can be both less-than AND equal-to 12. At any rate, you still have a lot of redundant code that can be simplified as I mentioned above. With this fix, it should still work... technically...